# How do I say "semantician/semanticist" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, linguistics

I recently came across the intriguing terms, 'semantician' and 'semanticist', both referring to a specialist in semantics. These words are derived from the Ancient Greek root 'sēmantikós'.

My query is twofold:

1. Is there a direct Latin equivalent to the English term from this Greek root?
2. If a direct equivalent does not exist, would it be more appropriate to coin a paraphrase in Latin that captures the same meaning?

Answer (score 3):

There is the adjective *[semanticus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsemanticus)*:

> Designating, having an indicative force, Mart. Cap. 9, §§ 985, 988.

Seems as though the only citation is that by 5th-century satirist Martianus Minneus Felix Capella.

There are adjectives like *mathematicus* which means both "mathematical" and "mathematician", which supports using an adjective like *semanticus* for "semantician".

Comment: A correction about the source: 'Mart.' doesn't refer here to Martial. Instead, according to the key to abbreviations at the front of Lewis & Short, 'Mart. Cap.' = the 5th century satirist Martianus Minneus Felix Capella.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake - thanks for catching! I edited my answer.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there are adjectives like *mathematicus* which mean both "mathematical" and "mathematician". That supports using an adjective similarly for "semantician".

Comment: Oh, good idea, @JoonasIlmavirta. I edited and added - thanks!